# Divide css for chrome and safari

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari

Is there any way to define different set of styles for chrome and for safari? Usually there's a webkit property which is for both of them but I need to divide them, is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try something like this: http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/

Answer (score 1):

you can use JavaScript JQuery functions to get the clients browser type and define specific CSS to the elements.!